# Need help understanding an article on parallel stream performance gains

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, java-stream

I have been reading this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/whats-wrong-java-8-part-iii) about parallel streams. It's quite long winded and I understood everything up to a part relating to how parallel streams work. I will quote the section I have difficulty understanding:

"Parallelization requires:
A pool of threads to execute the subtasks,
Dividing the initial task into subtasks,
Distributing subtasks to threads,
Collating the results.
Without entering the details, all this implies some overhead. It will show amazing results when:

- **Some tasks imply blocking for a long time, such as accessing a remote service, or**
- There are not many threads running at the same time, and in particular no other parallel stream.

If all subtasks imply intense calculation, the potential gain is limited by the number of available processors. Java 8 will by default use as many threads as they are processors on the computer, so, for intensive tasks, the result is highly dependent upon what other threads may be doing at the same time. **Of course, if each subtask is essentially waiting, the gain may appear to be huge.**"

I don't understand the 2 statements highlighted in bold above.

The first sentence: *Some tasks imply blocking for a long time, such as accessing a remote service*

My understanding is that performance gains would be large **relative** to the same tasks being executed in a concurrent programming environment as opposed to a parallel processing environment?

This one: *Of course, if each subtask is essentially waiting, the gain may appear to be huge.*

I haven't a clue what the author means here.

Comment: They're saying that for non-compute-limited tasks, parallelisation (or indeed, concurrency) will lead to a performance gain that is not limited by the total amount of compute resource.

Comment: Nope, sorry, I still don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any CPU-intensive task (e.g., sorting an array) eats up a portion of the CPU's processing power. Parallelization allows you to split the task up between multiple cores so you can use all the processing power that's available to the system. But your task has to compete with other tasks, thread pools, processes, the OS, etc. that also need to use the CPUs at the same time. So there's always a cap on how much computing power you can squeeze out of your processor. Hence,

> It will show amazing results when... There are not many threads running at the same time, and in particular no other parallel stream.

Now, let's say you have a task that needs to make 10 database calls. Each of those calls takes 1 second for the database to run the query, gather the results and return them to you. If you run that task in a single sequential thread, the execution time for those database calls will add up to 10 seconds in total, because each call can only run after the previous one has completed. During those 10 seconds, your program is essentially idle, doing nothing but waiting for a response.

Here is where parallelization really shines. If you split the task into 10 subtasks and run each of them in their own thread, they can each concurrently submit the query and wait for the result, which means you only have a 1 second of downtime overall. Because the subtasks are *blocking*, not *computing*, you're not limited by the available system resources. The only constraint is how far you can logically break down a single task. Hence,

> It will show amazing results when Some tasks imply blocking for a long time, such as accessing a remote service... if each subtask is essentially waiting, the gain may appear to be huge.

Comment: Of course, this heavily depends on the remote service’s capability of parallel processing of these requests sent in parallel. In the worst case, you gain nothing…